# Convert ListBox.ObjectCollection to String array in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, string, casting

I'm programming an application in VB.NET in which I need to take the Items from a ListBox, which are an ListBox.ObjectCollection and convert into a String array to be passed as a parameter to a Sub procedure.
How should I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming .NET 3.5, and thus LINQ:

```
(From item As Object In yourListBox.ObjectCollection Select item.ToString()).ToArray()
```

This also assumes that the way you want to convert items to strings is via `ToString()` - but, of course, you can replace it with anything else

Answer (score 0):

Updating for .NET 4.6

```
(From item In yourListBox.Items Select value = item.ToString).ToArray()
```